# Multiple search fields in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm still learning RoR and its taken me all day to figure out a simple search field that filters properties by the number of bedrooms. It's working perfectly now but I don't know if it's the right way to do it cos I can't figure out how to adapt it so that I can add extra search fields for bathrooms, minimum price, max price, zip etc.

The search field and submit button and the results are on the list page so in the controller I have:

```
def list
@properties = Property.bedrooms(params[:bedrooms])
end
```

in the model I have:

```
def self.bedrooms(bedrooms)
 if bedrooms
   find(:all, :conditions => ["bedrooms LIKE ?", "%#{bedrooms}%"])
 else
   find(:all)
 end
```

end

and the list.html.erb page is:

```
<%= form_tag( 'list', :method => 'get') do %>
<p>
<%= text_field_tag 'bedrooms', (params[:bedrooms]) %>

<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

How do I add a search field for bathrooms, another for minimum price, another for max price, another for zip etc? thanks, Adam

Am getting syntax errors when trying to add this to controller:

```
scope :bedrooms, {|b| where("bedrooms LIKE ?", b)}  
scope :price_greater, {|p|  where("price > ?", p)}
```

error is:

```
SyntaxError in PropertiesController#list

/Users/Adam/Documents/Websites/idx_app/app/models/property.rb:4: syntax error,    unexpected '|', expecting '}'
 scope :bedrooms, {|b| where("bedrooms LIKE ?", b)}  
                  ^
/Users/Adam/Documents/Websites/idx_app/app/models/property.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
scope :bedrooms, {|b| where("bedrooms LIKE ?", b)}  
                                                 ^
/Users/Adam/Documents/Websites/idx_app/app/models/property.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting '}'
scope :price_greater, {|p|  where("price > ?", p)}
                       ^
/Users/Adam/Documents/Websites/idx_app/app/models/property.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
```

Yes adding the lambdas fixed the above syntax errors but now it's as if the @properties is not returning an array because I'm getting the following error message:

```
undefined method `each' for #<Class:0x007fd5235250f8>

Extracted source (around line #29):

26:       <th>Price</th>
27:     
28:     </tr>
29:     <% @properties.each do |property| %>
30:     <tr>
31:       
32:       <td><%= link_to(property.address, {:action => 'show', :id => property.id}) %></td>
```

Fixed this error message, I hadn't defined it properly in the controller, I had put @properties.all instead of @properties = @properties.all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it by using scopes...

```
  scope :bedrooms, lambda{ |b| where("bedrooms LIKE ?", b) }    
  scope :price_greater, lambda{ |p|  where("price > ?", p)  }
```

in controller

```
  @properties = Property.scoped
  @properties = @properties.bedrooms(params[:bedrooms]) if params[:bedrooms].present?
  @properties = @properties.price_greater(params[:min]) if params[:min].present?
  .....
  @properties = @properties.paginate.... or just @properties.all
```

Comment: right I see, didn't realise you could keep redefining @properties on next line and adding more conditions to it, will try later and let you know, thanks very much for the answer

Comment: sry,fixed) forgot to add commas and lambdas

Comment: thanks the lamdas fixed those errors, see above for next error!

Comment: no I fixed that it was me doing it wrong so all is good, thanks very much for all your help, much appreciated

Comment: still having trouble getting the price_greater to work, will keep trying and let you know, is the params[:min] definitely correct?

Comment: do u have in your form text_field_tag :min ? and price attribute in your model?

Comment: right, I've got it working now, thanks again for all your help, Adam