# Multiple search fields in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Using Rails 4 and ruby 2.2, 
I have my User model which has following attributes

> 1. username
> 2. email
> 3. active

Now I need to create a search text field for username, email and drop down for active attributes. I have my

> user.rb

```
  def self.usernames(username)
      user = all
      user = user.where("username LIKE ?", "%#{username}%")
      return user
  end


  def self.emails(email)
    user = all
    user = user.where("email LIKE ?", "%#{email}%")
    return user
  end


  def self.actives(active)
    user = all
    user = user.where("active LIKE ?", "%#{active}%")
    return user
```

> users_controller.rb

```
 def index
    @users = User.all
    @users = @users.usernames(params[:username]) if params[:username].present?
    @users = @users.emails(params[:email]) if params[:email].present?
    @users = @users.actives(params[:active]) if params[:active].present?
  end
```

> index.html.erb

```
h1>Listing Users</h1>

<div id="forms">
    <%= form_tag users_path, :method=> "get" do %>

      <%= label_tag :username, "Name" %>
      <%= text_field_tag :username %>

      <%= label_tag :email, "Email" %>
      <%= text_field_tag :email%>

      <%= label_tag :active, "Active" %>
      <%= select_tag :active, options_for_select([['Active', true], ['Inactive', false]]) %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search" %> 
      <%= link_to "Clear Search", request.path, class:"cancel-button" %>
    <% end %>

</div>
<div id="users"><%= render "users" %></div>


<%= button_to "Create User", new_user_path, method: :get %>
```

> Schema.rb

```
 create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  limit: 255, default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     limit: 255, default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token",   limit: 255
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.string   "name",                   limit: 255
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          limit: 4,   default: 0,     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip",     limit: 255
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip",        limit: 255
    t.string   "confirmation_token",     limit: 255
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "unconfirmed_email",      limit: 255
    t.integer  "failed_attempts",        limit: 4,   default: 0,     null: false
    t.string   "unlock_token",           limit: 255
    t.datetime "locked_at"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "username",               limit: 255
    t.boolean  "active",                             default: false
```

Now when I am trying to filter by username or email, it is not giving me any result.

Following is the result in console,

```
Started GET "/users?utf8=%E2%9C%93&username=alok&email=&active=true&commit=Search" for ::1 at 2016-04-18 13:10:09 +0530
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "username"=>"alok", "email"=>"", "active"=>"true", "commit"=>"Search"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = ?  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 11]]
{"utf8"=>"✓", "username"=>"alok", "email"=>"", "active"=>"true", "commit"=>"Search", "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"index"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (username LIKE '%alok%') AND (active LIKE '%true%')
  Rendered users/_users.html.erb (7.2ms)
  Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (49.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 671ms (Views: 550.7ms | ActiveRecord: 49.9ms)
```

I have referred the following post but getting similar result,  no output,Please let me know if I am missing anything,

[Multiple search fields in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669765/multiple-search-fields-in-rails)

Comment: What type is the 'active' attribute in your user model?

Comment: boolean and default to false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in the function  def self.actives(active)

Try changing it to

```
 def self.actives(active)
    user = all
    user = user.where("active = ?", active)
    return user
end
```

You might also want to try the Ransack gem in order to easily add/remove fields at a search form
https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack